# What is a good method for rapidly cloning White Pumpkin plants?

Tags: pumpkins

I have six particular 40-day-old white pumpkin plants. I need to multiply these particular plants as rapidly as possible -- It's at least another month or two before I can extract viable seeds.

Am I better off utilizing the [bury-the-vine](http://www.bigpumpkins.com/ViewArticle.asp?id=31&gid=2) method? I am a bit concerned about what stage (how large) a pumpkin plant should be at before burying portions.

There is also the method that involves cutting the plant, dipping in root hormone, and placing in a greenhouse environment to supposedly promote new root development. I believe this method could multiple faster if it worked, but I'm hesitant to waste the effort on this if the bury-the-vine method is more suitable.

[image]

Comment: Why didn't you want to plant more seeds instead (if it's not a private matter)? It probably would have been easier.

Comment: @Shule This particular contest was setup where each participant was given a bag of seeds. They were to plant the seeds and see how many pumpkins could be grown. The timing was such that I could not afford to wait for generation 1's seeds to become viable for generation 2 (gen-2 would not have produced fruit until after the expiration of the contest). Thus, if I wanted a generation 2 to produce pumpkins, I was forced to clone relatively-young generation-1 plants.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one description online: [How to Clone Pumpkins off the Main Vine](http://www.bigpumpkins.com/ViewArticle.asp?id=31&gid=2), that might help.

> TECHNIQUES AND METHODS: Successful cloning off the main vines is as
>   simple as burying the vine in some soil, then waiting 7-10 days to cut
>   the new plant from the main plant. Many growers bury vines during the
>   season to give their plant an added root system which anchors and
>   feeds the main plant. To make pumpkin clones indoors {or out}, the
>   same basic principal is applied. Once the original pumpkin begins
>   growing over the container and has a vine long enough which can be
>   placed in another pot, all the grower must do is provide that vine a
>   rooting medium for the plant to do what is natural for it; sprout
>   roots. Bury the entire vine 1/2 inch below the soils surface in the
>   new pot. This is soon to be a new plant, of the same origin as the
>   original plant. Place a heating pad below the pot the clone is in, and
>   keep head on low or medium. The clone pot should be well watered, but
>   not overly saturated. It is helpful to use vitamin B-1, Superthrive
>   plant hormones, and Shultz 2-7-7{with micronutrients} Cactus Plus.
>   Using similar fertilizers will work as well. Both the host pot and
>   clone pot should then be put underneath a shop light which is kept on
>   24 hours a day. Check the clone plant after a couple days, and keep
>   the soil moist in that pot. The host pot needs little to no water
>   during this period. By stressing the host plant this way, the clone
>   becomes less dependent on the roots at the base of the host plant, and
>   is encouraged to sprout it's own roots. After 7-10 days if you have
>   given the new vine what it need to grow, the host plat can be cut
>   away. Cut the old vine away from the clone as close to the soil as
>   possible. Larger leaves which were buried earlier should be cut at
>   this time. This will allow the new plant to not have to care for so
>   many leaves initially, and allow the plant to root without stressing.
>   You now have a cloned pumpkin plant which has the same genetic makeup
>   as the host plant it was cut from! This process can be done again and
>   again and again.

Also see [Cloning Pumpkins](http://www.pumpkinnook.com/howto/clone.htm) for how-to steps.